# Insert / Convert date from: C++ To mySQL db

Tags: mysql, casting, c++-cli, datetime-format, str-to-date

I'm a beginner in c++, this is part of my Task for an interview. Everything else works fine, except that I **don't know how to convert String to Date**, when it comes to pass the record to the database. Or just pass date (or DateTime) to the database. I found a lot of things in google, but couldn't figure it out how to do this in the most simple way. Also later **I'll add HH:mm**, because I'll have to calculate with hours/mins too. Here's the part of the code:

DateTime **startTime** = dateTimePicker1->Value;
String^ **startTimeString** = **startTime**.Year.ToString() +"-"+ **startTime**.Month.ToString() +"-"+ **startTime**.Day.ToString();

MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("insert into activity_db values('" + name + "','" + category + "',***'SELECT STR_TO_DATE(" + startTimeString + ",%Y-%m-%d)'***)", con);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
MySqlCommand^ cmd = gcnew MySqlCommand("insert into activity_db values('" + name + "','" + category + "',STR_TO_DATE('" + startTimeString + "','%Y-%m-%d'))", con);
```

So you will get  the correct mysql command

```
insert into activity_db values('name','category',STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'))
```

And you should urgenty takem alook at [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it works. About prepared statements: I knew that something like this exists, but didnt know how to look for it. Well I'm still learning.